# Adding new xElement after ALL found Descendants

Tags: search, linq-to-xml, xelement, xattribute

I have an xDocument with multiple various xElements.

I can successfully find a specific xElement by searching via it's xAttributes & then Add a new xElement after it using the code below:

`xDocument.Descendants("td").LastOrDefault(e => ((string)e.Attribute("ID")) == "3").Add(new XElement("b", "Just a test."));`

The problem is that I wish to Add this new xElement after all found instances of the Descendants, not just LastOrDefault or FirstOrDefault.

My xDocument is created dynamically & there is no way before hand to know how many 'td' xElements with 'ID' = '3' that there are going to be.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

---

ADDED CODE AS REQUESTED

```
<html> .... etc....  
    <body> 
    <table> 
    <tr> 
    <td>Image</td>
    <td>Description</td> 
    <td>Date</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td ID="1">*.jpg</td>
    <td ID="2">some image</td>
    <td ID="3">01/01/1901</td>  <--CHANGING THIS PART OF CODE--> 
    <--THIS TABLE ROW REPEATS AN UNDETERMINED NUMBER
    OF TIMES RELATING TO THE NUMBER OF FILES CONTAINED IN WHATEVER DIRECTORY IS BEING SEARCHED USING A FOREACH LOOP IN ANOTHER PART OF
    THE CODE--> 
    </tr> 
    </table> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

So I am trying to add a  tag between the `<td>` with ID = 3. 
This `<b>` tag also contains a string variable i.e. 
`new xElement("b", DateTaken)`
& needs to be created at runtime and not hard coded as it relates to each loaded image at the start of the table row.

So I am trying to add this `<b>` tag to every occurrence of `<td>` with ID=3 & not just the first or the last.

Hope this extra info helps.

Comment: Can you show an example of xml before and after the addition?

Comment: I'll add additional code tomorrow when back in my PC, impossible to enter code here via iPhone.

Comment: @foggy i have added the extra code, thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it something like `xDocument.Descendants("td").Where(e => ((string)e.Attribute("ID")) == "3").Add(new XElement("b", "Just a test."));` work?  I.e., use a `Where` to filter the results and add the new element after each matching occcurence?

Comment: @tim thanks I'll have a look at that